# Can't drag and drop multiple emails from IBM Notes 9 onto file system folder

Tags: windows-7, email, lotus-notes, drag-and-drop

I'm using IBM Notes 9 Social Edition and I want to drag and drop multiple emails into a Windows file system folder (as .eml files).

I can do it with one email at a time but not with multiple.

I have the setting "Show check marks in margin for selected documents" enabled and I can 'select' multiple emails (meaning that they get a check mark). But dragging and dropping from any of these checked emails only results in one email being dropped as an .eml file.

Using Copy from the Edit Menu doesn't work either as this does not result into anything in the Windows clipboard.

EDIT: I'm using very old Lotus Notes databases.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this should work, and I just tested and it worked for me: I can drag and drop as many mails to the desktop as I want. 
Did you enable the Option "Show >> Beginning of message"? Because this can cause the error you decribe. [Check out this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21633979&myns=swglotus&mynp=OCSSKTWP&mync=E)

Comment: I don't have this option, perhaps because I'm using very old notes databases. But I have disabled Previews so this is probably not the problem. I have found a solution, see my answer.

Comment: Then you should have stated, that you do NOT use the Notes 9 Mailtemplate...

Comment: OK, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This `Email Export agent for Notes` solved the problem:

http://tech.niques.info/projects/lotus-notes-email-export

(I know this URL looks like crap but it is a good solution, it's not some commercial link. Several other sources refer to it.)